# Why is the preposition "in" used twice in this sentence: In 1934, in February...?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

This sentence is in the book pattern complete sentence is:

> In 1934, in February, when the dust was still so thick in the Minnesota air that my parents couldn't always see from the house to the barn, their fifth child – a fourth daughter – was born.  ― *[MY MOTHER NEVER WORKED](http://www2.moundsviewschools.org/irondale/userfiles/clemsonn/college%20english/my_mother_never_worked.pdf)*, by Bonnie Smith-Yackel, page 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason I might say 'In my house, in the kitchen, there is an oven', or 'In my car in the glove compartment, there are some keys'.

I could avoid all that by saying 'In my kitchen at home there is an oven' or 'There are some keys in the glove compartment of my car'.

In the same way your author might have said: 'In February 1934, when the dust....'

Comment: In a cav-ern, in a can-yon ...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you could say "in February 1934". But it may be intentional to describe it that way--in 1934, in February.

The author may want to convey something more than the plain expression "in February 1934".

Comment: How is this answer different or better than Shoe's?

Answer (score 1):

You need only one *in* if *February* precedes the year: *in February 1934*.

If you place *February* after the year, then you need the second *in*. Separating the month from the year in this way gives it more prominence, which is likely to have been the writer's intention.

Answer (score 0):

Minnesota winters are particularly brutal with the cold, the humidity and, in this case, the dust and wind--perhaps on account of the [Dust Bowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_Bowl)--and my critical sense is that the author is stressing both the difficulty of the time period and the difficulty of the season.

In this case, we could cite the repetition of "in" as an instance of [anaphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28rhetoric%29), emphasizing both the burden of the time in years and in seasons.